# Python set working directory like Intellij in terminal

Tags: python, intellij-idea, python-import

I have a python which has the following folder/file structure.

```
Project/
-- generic_module
-- directory
---- sub_directory
------ main.py (uses generic_module, & other imports are relative to Project)
```

Now if I want to run main.py via Intellij IDE, I can just set the "Working Directory" in the run configuration and it works fine.
[image]

I want to run it via terminal without Intellij IDE. In that case what do I do ?

I tried things like "python directory/sub_directory/main.py" from the Project/ folder, but still I am facing import errors.

Comment: If the problem is your import path, you can do `sys.path.append(...)` to add a folder to your Python path, and you can use `os.abspath(os.dirname(__file__)+"../..")` (for example) to get a path relative to the location of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDE behind the hoods changes the pythonpath env variable.
So run the python script via terminal one could do it in two ways

**Powershell**

```
$env:PYTHONPATH+=";<path_of_directories_containing_the_imports>
```

> Other shell such as bash, etc change the env "PYTHONPATH" as shown

**Pythonic way** (*thanks to Tim Roberts comments*)

```
sys.path.append(...)
```

*or*

```
os.abspath(os.dirname(__file__)+"../..")
```